# Get value of a different object 'field' using Alpine Js in Laravel blade component SELECT Element

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I have a blade component which shows a list of properties - the  values are the property ids - the `SELECT` component is populated by an object called `$properties` which has the `id, name, add1` fields. How do I bind (update) the `$property->add1` to an `input element - con_add1` on select change.

The code that I have is:

```xml
<div x-data="{ add1: '{{$contract->con_add1}}' }">
    ...
    <select id="con_tid" name="con_tid" x-on:change="add1=$event.target.value">
        @foreach ($properties as $property)
            <option value="{{ $property->id }}" {{ old('con_tid', $contract->con_tid) === $property->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                {{ $property->code . ' - ' . $property->name }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    ...
    <x-input type="text" name="con_add1" value="{{ old('con_add1', $contract->con_add1) }}" x-model="add1" />
```

Comment: Does this work on a regular `<input>` element? Have you tried using `this` in the `x-on:change` attribute?  (`x-on:change="this.add1 = $event.target.value"`)

Comment: As expected, it returns the $property->id value

Answer (score 0):

For someone who may be looking for an answer. I resolved this as follows:

```
<div x-data="initialize" }">
    ...
    <select id="con_tid" name="con_tid" x-on:change="getValues($event.target.value)">
        @foreach ($properties as $property)
            <option value="{{ $property->id }}" {{ old('con_tid', $contract->con_tid) === $property->id ? 'selected' : '' }} data-add1="{{$property->add1}}" id="{{'option' . $property->id}}">
                {{ $property->code . ' - ' . $property->name }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    ...
    <x-input type="text" name="con_add1" value="{{ old('con_add1', $contract->con_add1) }}" x-model="add1" />
.
.
<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('initialize', () => ({
            add1: '{{$contract->con_add1}}',

            getValues(selectedOption) {
                selectedProperty = document.getElementById('option'+selectedOption);
                this.add1 = selectedProperty.getAttribute('data-add1');

            }
        }))
    })
</script>
```